# Can laravel blade service injection can be done from outside view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I want to inject service globally for all application views
can i inject it thorough application service provider boot method ?

Answer (score 3):

What service you want to inject? How will you use it?

An easy way to share variables across all views is to call the `share` method:

```
view()->share([

    'myService' => app()->make(My\Service::class),
]);
```

You can call this within your controller or maybe inside a middleware to work across many different controllers, too.

Then, in your views, something like this:

```
@foreach ($myService->getItems() as $item)
    ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, Is it something similar to adding @inject('myService', 'My\Service::class'); in each blade template

Comment: **Cool** Thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Follow this steps:

create service provider: `php artisan make:provider UserServiceProvider`

Go to

> app\providers\UserServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Auth;

class UserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot()
    { 
        // key can be anything
        // value what you want
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

Than register this service provider inside the `config\app.php`

```
App\Providers\UserServiceProvider::class,
```

Now you can access this `key` for every views.